# Bypass activate storage for android phone?

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have an android phone with broking screen that I'd like to root to eventually use it for a different purpose (as a computer).

The thing is that when I connect it to my computer it is detected, but as I recall, I have to activate access to storage on the phone before, which I can't do since the screen is broking.

Output to lsusb (on linux): Bus 001 Device 043: ID 0bb4:0001 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)

In device manager (on win7 64bit): [image: phone in the device manager]

(Solution on windows or linux CLI are both fine by me)

Also if there is a hardware solution to this problem, I'm open to it